# Bootstrap images not aligning properly in Explorer, Firefox

Tags: image, twitter-bootstrap, firefox, alignment, explorer

My Boostrap framework is working fine on Chrome and Safari. It also is mostly on Explorer and Firefox. However, in Explorer and Firefox, a couple of images on interior pages appear to have an offset applied. The issue will be apparent when viewing the pages:

[notagamebook.com/the-author-2](http://notagamebook.com/the-author-2)
[notagamebook.com/excerpts](http://notagamebook.com/excerpts)

I have been unable to find anyone else who has encountered the same issue. And I realize a manual fix won't be all that difficult, but I would like to keep the images in the framework and figure out what is happening in case it occurs again in the future.

**EDIT**
After attempting to fix this issue manually, I have realized it is NOT a Bootstrap issue. Firefox and Explorer are pushing the first piece of content following the page label to the right. It did so even when coding outside of the Bootstrap framework. I tried putting a piece of text as the first item and got the same result.

Comment: Can you add some screen shots of the problem? And code snippets too. Use [jsFiddle](www.jsfiddle.net).

Comment: I checked it in Firefox and Its weird, it should be working if you used the class `pull-left` on the `img` tag and/or `float: left` on `CSS`

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution to this problem: There was a difference in the bottom margin being applied to the title in Explorer and Firefox, pushing the content to the right of the title div.